# Obtaining a tighter bound on difference of norms

Tags: vector-spaces, vectors, normed-spaces, matrix-norms

Say we have a real-valued vector $x \in \mathbb{R}^p$. Now say we construct another vector $y$, where we take a small scalar $c>0$ away from each entry of $x$, where $c$ is smaller than each entry of $x$. We can bound the difference of the $\ell_2$ norms by

$$||y ||_2 -|| x||_2 \leq || y-x||_2 = ||-c||_2  =||c||_2$$.

However, as $||y ||_2 -|| x||_2 \leq 0$, the bound changes symbol. I wonder if we can find a bound from above such that it remains below 0?

Answer (score 1):

The correct relation is
$$
\Big|\|y\|_2-\|x\|_2\Big|\leq\|c\|_2
$$
so that
$$
-\|c\|_2\leq\|y\|_2-\|x\|_2\leq\|c\|_2
$$

Comment: I still don't have a bound that remains below 0, as $\|c\|_2 \geq 0$.